# What is the difference between dbcontext and POCO templates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, dbcontext

I can see in the manager extensions, that exists EF 4.x dbcontext and EF 4.x POCO. Both of them generate entities for persistence ignorant.

What are the difference between them?

What are the difference between 4.x and 5.x? which is the new features of the 5.x version?

Is it possible to use only one exchange entities for all the ways to access to the database? I would like to use an interface to use different ways to access to the database. EF 4, EF 5 and others than not necessary it would be EF. I would like to program once and use it in many scenarios.

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbContext is your gateway to all the entities in your model. For instance, if your context was called con, you might call con.Orders() to get to your Order objects. POCOs (plain old CLR objects) generated with Entity Framework do not extend classes from the Entity Framework. POCOs with Entity Framework are more advanced, so I recommend you not use them when getting started. One of the new features with EF 5 is replacement of DbContext with ObjectContext. OK, not replacement, because you can still use the DbContext. But Microsoft wants ObjectContext to be the new simpler way to access all your entities instead of DbContext. ObjectContext is much easier to work with in most cases.